# Smart Tags For Custom Control Doesn't Show Up

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, design-time

I have implemented a custom control but for it working, I must extend the design-time support for the control and create smart tags. I create a custom Designer class derived from `ControlDesigner`, a `DesignerActionList` and add the `DesignerActionList` to the `CustomDesigner::ActionLists` appropriately but when I switch to the Winforms Designer, I cannot see the smart tags panel. Whatever I try, I cannot succeed. I tried the example in the documentation but the smart tags also don't show up for the custom control `ColorLabel`.

I am following the exact procedure in the documentation example. So, if you try to reproduce the issue. You can refer to that. Also, I use **.Net 6 Winforms Application**.

**The sample custom control and Designer for it**:

```
[Designer(typeof(ColorLabelDesigner))]
public class ColorLabel : Label
{
    private bool colorLockedValue = false;

    public bool ColorLocked
    {
        get
        {
            return colorLockedValue;
        }
        set
        {
            colorLockedValue = value;
        }
    }

    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BackColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ColorLocked)
                return;
            else
                base.BackColor = value;
        }
    }

    public override Color ForeColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.ForeColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ColorLocked)
                return;
            else
                base.ForeColor = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public class ColorLabelDesigner :
          ControlDesigner
{
    private DesignerActionListCollection actionLists; 
    public override DesignerActionListCollection ActionLists
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == actionLists)
            {
                actionLists = new DesignerActionListCollection();
                actionLists.Add(
                    new ColorLabelActionList(this.Component));
            }
            return actionLists;
        }
    }
} 
public class ColorLabelActionList :
          System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerActionList
{
    private ColorLabel colLabel;

    private DesignerActionUIService designerActionUISvc = null; 
    public ColorLabelActionList(IComponent component) : base(component)
    {
        this.colLabel = component as ColorLabel; 
        this.designerActionUISvc =
            GetService(typeof(DesignerActionUIService))
            as DesignerActionUIService;
    } 
    private PropertyDescriptor GetPropertyByName(String propName)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop;
        prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(colLabel)[propName];
        if (null == prop)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                 "Matching ColorLabel property not found!",
                  propName);
        else
            return prop;
    } 
    public Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return colLabel.BackColor;
        }
        set
        {
            GetPropertyByName("BackColor").SetValue(colLabel, value);
        }
    }

    public Color ForeColor
    {
        get
        {
            return colLabel.ForeColor;
        }
        set
        {
            GetPropertyByName("ForeColor").SetValue(colLabel, value);
        }
    }
     
    public bool LockColors
    {
        get
        {
            return colLabel.ColorLocked;
        }
        set
        {
            GetPropertyByName("ColorLocked").SetValue(colLabel, value); 
            this.designerActionUISvc.Refresh(this.Component);
        }
    }

    public String Text
    {
        get
        {
            return colLabel.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            GetPropertyByName("Text").SetValue(colLabel, value);
        }
    } 
    public void InvertColors()
    {
        Color currentBackColor = colLabel.BackColor;
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(
            255 - currentBackColor.R,
            255 - currentBackColor.G,
            255 - currentBackColor.B);

        Color currentForeColor = colLabel.ForeColor;
        ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(
            255 - currentForeColor.R,
            255 - currentForeColor.G,
            255 - currentForeColor.B);
    } 
    public override DesignerActionItemCollection GetSortedActionItems()
    {
        DesignerActionItemCollection items = new DesignerActionItemCollection();

        //Define static section header entries.
        items.Add(new DesignerActionHeaderItem("Appearance"));
        items.Add(new DesignerActionHeaderItem("Information"));

        //Boolean property for locking color selections.
        items.Add(new DesignerActionPropertyItem("LockColors",
                         "Lock Colors", "Appearance",
                         "Locks the color properties."));
        if (!LockColors)
        {
            items.Add(new DesignerActionPropertyItem("BackColor",
                             "Back Color", "Appearance",
                             "Selects the background color."));
            items.Add(new DesignerActionPropertyItem("ForeColor",
                             "Fore Color", "Appearance",
                             "Selects the foreground color."));
             
            items.Add(new DesignerActionMethodItem(this,
                             "InvertColors", "Invert Colors",
                             "Appearance",
                             "Inverts the fore and background colors.",
                              true));
        }

        items.Add(new DesignerActionPropertyItem("Text",
            "Text String", "Appearance",
            "Sets the display text."));
        StringBuilder location = new StringBuilder("Location: ");
        location.Append(colLabel.Location);
        StringBuilder size = new StringBuilder("Size: ");
        size.Append(colLabel.Size);
        items.Add(new DesignerActionTextItem(location.ToString(),
                         "Information"));
        items.Add(new DesignerActionTextItem(size.ToString(),
                         "Information"));

        return items;
    }
}
```

There should be some configurations that are missing but I have no previous experience on Design-Time Development.

**The question** is not about ***How to create the smart tags*** but ***How can I add the smart tags for my custom control properly so that it shows up?***

Comment: You have a .Net 6 Project, so no luck. Test that Custom Control in a .Net Fx 4.8 Project

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. Where is it specified? What is the reason?

Comment: Yep, I tested it in a .Net Framework 4.8 Project and it worked.

Comment: [Smart Tag support in WF - issue #4887](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/4887) -- Not all designers have been ported. Some never will be (in the current form, at least). There's [a work-around](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WinForms.Designer.SDK#supportedframeworks-body-tab) (incomplete)